# Best Module to Layout Text in Python

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, cairo, graphic

I am looking to write a program which outputs a bunch (around 30) of boxes like in this image:

[image: market watchlist]

I have been researching for weeks, I thought that to layout text in a graphically pleasing way I could use QTableWidget in PyQT, but I now realise that it is far too difficult to learn for such a simple task, there must be a quicker way. So I am thinking now to pass to Tkinter or maybe just draw the information with a Drawing Module like PyCairo and only then place each image in a PyQT interface. Sorting out all the positioning in a drawing module would be much quicker than learning how to do the same in PyQT.

But I feel I am missing something, I would have thought a much easier task to layout in a nice way a bunch of numbers in a repetitive format.

Some of the boxes will need also some graphical content has bars and charts for which I though to use plotly or cairo.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking too simple, but have you thought about generating a HTML page and use CSS to arrange the boxes? Would allow for dynamic layout when window dimensions change also?

Comment: that actually makes a lot of sense... I am newbie and there is so many answers for a question like mine that I simply got lost in them. Any advise on tutorials on this topic? to put plots/bars in that same page what would you say is best?

Comment: As Aminius suggested, you can format the text using a [Subset of HTML and CSS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) and put it in a `QLabel`. The simplest way to layout the text would be to use an html table.

Comment: does Django have anything to do with all of this? or it is not necessary?

Comment: @user3755529. No. You just want to look for a very basic tutorial on html. There are probably thousands of such things on the internet.

Comment: http://weasyprint.org/ maybe?

Comment: Qt is just fine for this. I would use a grid layout and then in the simplest way QLabels as widgets in the layout with html content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you're probably better off doing this with HTML and CSS as has been mentioned above, this isn't too difficult to do with Python and can be achieved with the use of just `tkinter`. Please see my code below for an example of how this could work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = []
frame2 = []
c = 0
numberofboxes = 8 #change this to increase the number of boxes

for i in range(numberofboxes):
    if i % 4 == 0: #checks if the current box is the fourth in row
        c = c + 1 #if the current box is the forth in the row then this runs and increases a counter which we later use to determine the row
    if len(frame1) != c: #checks if the number of rows currently existing matches the number there should be
        frame1.append(Frame(root)) #if the numbers don't match this runs and creates a new frame which acts as another row
        frame1[c-1].pack(expand="True", fill="both") #packs the new row
    frame2.append(Frame(frame1[c-1], bg="green")) #this is where the boxes are created
    frame2[i].pack(ipadx="50", ipady="50", side="left", padx="10", pady="10", expand="True", fill="both") #this is where the boxes are placed on the screen

for i in range(len(frame2)): #this for loop places the items inside each box, all of this can be replaced with whatever is needed
    Label(frame2[i], text="CO"+str(i), bg="green", fg="white").pack(side="top", anchor="w")
    Label(frame2[i], text="12165.1"+str(i), bg="green", fg="white").pack(side="top", anchor="w")
    Label(frame2[i], text="+60.7"+str(i), bg="green", fg="white").pack(side="bottom", anchor="e")
    Label(frame2[i], text="+1.2"+str(i)+"%", bg="green", fg="white").pack(side="bottom", anchor="e")

root.mainloop()
```

So essentially, we create a `frame` for each row and each box is a `frame` which has elements packed inside it and is fitted in the "row `frame`" 4 to each row.

You should take a close look at all of the options for `.pack()` during this script as well as they are necessary to achieve the desired layout and results.

For your triangles you would most likely need to either import an image or draw them within a `canvas` positioned properly or (as was pointed out by Bryan Oakley below) you could use unicode characters for the arrows, which would be an awful lot simpler.

Comment: There are unicode characters that can be used for the triangles in an otherwise text-only display.

Comment: Updated to reflect

Comment: Tkinter is not inside the tags

Comment: @eyllanesc no it isn't however the OP said "So I am thinking now to pass to Tkinter or maybe just draw the informations with a Drawing Module like PyCairo and only then place each image in a PyQT interface.". Therefore I provided a solution which uses tkinter to show it was possible.

Comment: fantastic, lots of information for me to start getting what I want.. if anyone is interested to see the full story and my development here it is https://github.com/AskBid/scrap-custom-trading-watchlist, warning n00b coding